# VBA Mis-Match Error 13

Tags: excel, vba, type-mismatch

I'm relatively new to VBA, I wrote a Sub to parse CSV information that is contained in a single cell and return certain pieces of data to other cells in the spreadsheet. Its a relatively simple code but I can't find the error. Its a Err 13 Mismatch on the line `Moods = Application.Index(fullArray, 0, 3)` Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Private Sub parseCSV()
'Parse "Notes" column and return Moods/Keywords to their apropriate cells

    Dim CSV As String
    Dim fullArray As Variant
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim Keywords As Variant
    Dim Moods As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    lRow = ActiveSheet().Range("BL" & ActiveSheet().Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 3 To lRow

        CSV = ActiveSheet.Range("BL" & i)            
        fullArray = Split(CSV, Chr(10))
        Moods = Application.Index(fullArray, 0, 3)
        Keywords = Application.Index(fullArray, 0, 2)

        ActiveSheet.Range("CD" & i).Value = Moods
        ActiveSheet.Range("CE" & i).Value = Keywords

    Next i

End Sub
```

I tested the parse function below:

```
Private Sub parseCSVTest()
'Parse "Notes" column and return Moods/Keywords to their apropriate cells

    Dim CSV As String
    CSV = ActiveSheet.Range("BL5")

    Dim fullArray As Variant
    fullArray = Split(CSV, Chr(10))

    Dim Moods As Variant
    Moods = Application.Index(fullArray, 0, 3)

    Dim Keywords As Variant
    Keywords = Application.Index(fullArray, 0, 2)

    ActiveSheet.Range("CD5").Value = Moods
    ActiveSheet.Range("CE5").Value = Keywords

End Sub
```

Works just fine. So I tested my loop.

```
Private Sub loopTest()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim lRow As Long
    lRow = ActiveSheet().Range("BL" & ActiveSheet().Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


    For i = 3 To lRow
        ActiveSheet.Range("CD" & i).Value = "testing"
    Next i

End Sub
```

Works fine. I don't know where to go from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Got it. Thanks for all the help everyone, this was a brain buster. For some reason

```
Moods = Application.Index(fullArray, 0, 3)
Keywords = Application.Index(fullArray, 0, 2)
```

won't return a value while specifying an entire column ( (0, 0) = all rows in columns in VBA Arrays ). I simply changed the array references to be (1, 3) and (1, 2). The full working code is below. This is the simplest way I've found online to parse to data from a cell and slice the array. Thanks to everyone that helped with this.

```
Private Sub parseCSV()
'Parse "Notes" column and return Moods/Keywords to their apropriate cells

    Dim CSV As String
    Dim fullArray As Variant
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim Keywords As Variant
    Dim Moods As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    lRow = ActiveSheet().Range("BL" & ActiveSheet().Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 3 To lRow

        CSV = ActiveSheet.Range("BL" & i)
        fullArray = Split(CSV, Chr(10))
        Moods = Application.Index(fullArray, 1, 2)
        Keywords = Application.Index(fullArray, 1, 3)

        ActiveSheet.Range("CE" & i).Value = Moods
        ActiveSheet.Range("CD" & i).Value = Keywords

    Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: Called the game too soon everyone. This works on Excel 2007 on my PC, but not on Excel 2011 on my Mac. Any ideas on this one. It seems on the Excell 2011 the statement `fullArray = Split(CSV, Chr(10))` isn't parsing my data and passing it into an array. If my data in the cell is "A (line break) B (line break) C, only A seems to be being passed into my array. So confusing.

Comment: Solved, on Mac/Office 2011 the only line break reference that works with the `Split()` statement is `vbNewLine` This worked once I changed  `fullArray = Split(CSV, Chr(10))` to fullArray = `Split(CSV, vbNewLine)`

Answer (score 1):

You are using **CSV** before you have assigned a value to it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I rearranged the code but no cigar. I still get the same mismatch error on the same line. It was a good catch though. Its edited to reflect the change in the question above.

Comment: @JamieMarshall  The next thing to check is: you are "feeding" *Index()* an array of strings.  It might need an array of numbers??

Comment: Thanks for the thought but i tested that when i tested my parse function. The `fullArray` variable stores the array as a Variant before feeding it to  Index(). That's what makes it work. I did however just test the actual data in the cells after i read your comment. I also limited the loop to 5 iterations (just so i know the data was fine). Noting.

Comment: Development: If i change my `Moods = Application.Index(fullArray, 0, 3) Keywords = Application.Index(fullArray, 0, 2)` to `Moods = Application.Index(fullArray, 0, 1)
        Keywords = Application.Index(fullArray, 0, 1)` it works. I get the wrong info in the wrong cells, but all the parts are moving. So why is my array empty at `(0, 2)` and `(0, 3)` ?

Comment: If *fullArray* is just a one dimension zero-based array, why not use **Moods=fullArray(2)**

Comment: No familiar with returning elements of an array that way. But if i use it in my `parseCVSTest` Sub get "err 9 subscript out of range"